# Replace HTML values using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code in HTML and wanted to replace them using javascript

Original code

```
<td class="tabButton dijitHidden tweetsTabButton selectedTab" dojoattachpoint="tweetsTabButton" data-type="twitter" style="display: none;">
Tweets
<div class="arrow-up"><div class="arrow-up-content"></div></div>
</td>
```

Replace it to

```
<td  dojoattachpoint="tweetsTabButton" data-type="twitter" style="display: none;">
<h2>Tweets</h2>

</td>
```

Comment: So... remove the `class` of the `<td>` and replace `Tweets` with `<h2>Tweets</h2>`, then remove the exact text `<div class="arrow-up">`? If that's not it, then what will this data have in common?

Comment: @Marcin I love that link. That will help me spend less time on this site.

Comment: @Hippo I have it bookmarked, so I can drag it to the comment box.

Comment: @bumblebee: Why is this question tagged with css? What have you tried?  Do you use any JavaScript frame. We need more information if you want to have any help. Precise questions --> precise answers!

Comment: @Marcin, yes that is what I want to do > I want the header to be bigger, so want to remove the class in the <td> and add <h2>.

Comment: @bumblebee, do you use the jQuery Library ?

Comment: @Marcin now that's useful info! Time to bookmark all of Meta's What Stack Overflow Is Not posts. [Stack Overflow is not a research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/186879). And welcome OP btw.

Comment: @zuul I am new to javascript. We do use dojo

Comment: @bumblebee You have `<div class="arrow-up">` in the original HTML, where does that `div` close?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Sorry my bad. I did not paste the complete tag. It is <div class="arrow-up">
<div class="arrow-up-content"></div>
</div>

Comment: I'm not too sure about how to get the `Tweets` textNode and replace it by a `h2` element in pure JS, but now the question should be answerable.

Comment: @bumblebee, placed an answer with a Fiddle link based on the current question and followed comments.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, I did not remember the suffering to make something like this :)

Comment: @Zuul Nicely done man, there's possibly an easier way around if the final markup is something as simple as what OP is asking. `:P` Let's see what I can put together..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the question contents, and the comments currently present, you need to:

1. wrap the text `Tweets` with an element, specifically `<h2></h2>`
2. remove the `class` attribute from the `td` to disable CSS
3. use pure JavaScript
4. Assuming a `table` `ID` present and using the `data-type` attribute as verification!

See this [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/Bcb7r/) Example!

**javaScript**

```
// get the table by ID
var table = document.getElementById("table-id");   

// get the table cells
var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("td");   

// for each table cell found
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {   

    // get the attribute 'data-type'
    var status = cells[i].getAttribute("data-type");

    // if 'data-type' contains the value 'twitter'
    if ( status == "twitter" ) {   

        // create the 'h2' element
        var h2 = document.createElement("h2");

            // append a textnode to the created element with the text 'Tweets'
            h2.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Tweets'));

        // remove the current text 'Tweets'
        cells[i].removeChild(cells[i].firstChild);


        // remove the class atrribute
        cells[i].removeAttribute('class');

        // append the new element to the current 'td'
        cells[i].appendChild(h2);
    }  
}
```

**Note:** Could be optimized, but as is you can see what's happening. Also the comments are there to guide you through, remove when in production.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way around:

```
//index [0] assumes you want to modify the first td matching this set of class rules..
var td = document.getElementsByClassName("tabButton dijitHidden tweetsTabButton selectedTab")[0];

//remove the attributes, as requested
td.removeAttribute('class');
td.removeAttribute('dojoattachpoint');

//sets the innerHTML of the element, overwriting the original one
td.innerHTML = '<h2>Tweets</h2>';
```

Note that the `td` will still have `display:none` which makes it invisible, you may add:

```
td.style.display = "table-cell";
```

To make it visible dynamically. Don't forget to run the script after the DOM is ready/loaded.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/Lfxur/)

Comment: Thanks for your post @Fabricio. I will also try this